# When is a heredoc's output expanded?

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

I'm trying to understand how the bash works from the inside, and I have a problem understanding why the heredoc's output gets expanded when we set a delimiter without quotes and get expanded with them.

For example :
Delimiter without quotes

```
  bash-3.2$ cat << a
    > test
    > $SHELL
    > a
    test
    /bin/zsh
```

Delimiter with quotes :

```
bash-3.2$ cat << 'a'
> test
> $SHELL
> a
test
$SHELL
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the heredoc delimiter as `'a'` or `"a"` or `\a` or any other way causes the heredoc to be treated literally with expansion disabled. This is a useful feature for cases where you don't want dollar signs and other special characters to be expanded: for example, when the heredoc contains an embedded shell script.

This behavior is described in the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) (emphasis added):

> #### 3.6.6 Here Documents
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only *word* (with no trailing blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input (or file descriptor *n* if *n* is specified) for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> [n]<<[-]word
>         here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or filename expansion is performed on *word*. **If any part of *word* is quoted,** the *delimiter* is the result of quote removal on *word*, and **the lines in the here-document are not expanded**. If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence `\newline` is ignored, and `\` must be used to quote the characters `\`, `$`, and `` ` ``.
>
> If the redirection operator is `<<-`, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing *delimiter*. This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.